# if $A-B$ and $B$ are both positive semidefinite then $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are both Hermitian. Also let $B$ and $A-B$ be positive semidefinite. Show there exists a non singular matrix $C$ such that $C^* A C$ and $C^* B C$ are both diagonal.

I found a proof for when $A$ and $B$ are both positive definite but the $C$ they prescribe while it worked seemed to come out of no where. I've thought for a while on how to define a $C$ such that they both become diagonal but haven't had any luck.

A couple of things that I know we have at our disposal is that postive semidefinite matrices are unitarily diagonalizable, and they have a cholesky factorization.

Thanks in advance for any help!